# Websocket in pending state and can not established with proxy

Tags: proxy, websocket

I'm trying to run a Websocket server at workplace, but unfortunately I always got **Pending** state and can not establish the connection.

Furthermore, I got a website: [Websocket Echo Test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) and found that I can't establish it either.

error message like this: `DISCONNECTED`

Maybe the proxy configuration in my workplace is why I can not establish the Websocket connection.

---

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *John* for help me edited this question.

Issue fixed.

I updated `< plugin>` version to `8.1.2.v20120308` and everything goes well.

```
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- 8.0.0.M2 -->
                    <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version> 
                </plugin>
```